# Unwrapping Optional value for inout parameter in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

Suppose I have a function that takes inout parameter:

```
func foo(param: inout Int?) {
   //I want to convert param to Int here without using return

}
```

I want to unwrap the parameter inside the func without having to return it. I know there are many ways to unwrap optional but I need to do it inside a function to reuse it without having to rewrite something like:

```
if let foo = someOptionalFoo {

}
```

several times in code. Thank you.

Comment: Unclear what the goal is. You cannot turn an Optional into a nonOptional. This is probably an xy question.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, i don't want to repeat unwrapping code for different variables. I want a reusable function that's why.

Comment: Are you trying unwrap that variable, and keep it in unwrapped in the next lines?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use it in next lines.

Comment: You can’t make an optional into a non-optional this way. You still have to deal with the optional case. Like what happens if it’s nil? Etc...

Comment: “I want a reusable function that's why” But the unwrap operator _is_ the “reusable function”. If `foo` is a nonnil Optional, `foo!` is the unwrapped version. You don’t need to write a function that unwraps; unwrapping already exists.

Comment: _Yes, I'm trying to use it in next lines._ You can't do that using the **existing** variable. You need to create a **new** property that is non-optional! You would do that using a `if let` or `guard let`...

Answer (score 0):

```
func foo(param: inout Int?) {
    //I want to convert param to Int here without using return

}

var bar: Int? = 5

foo(param: &bar)

print("\(bar)") //Optional(5)
```

Do you want that to print just 5, without Optional? If so, I don't think that this is possible. `bar` is typed as being optional. There should be no way to change the type of that variable in general, or from another scope.

What would be possible is that you just make sure that after calling `foo` on `bar`, you define `foo` to make sure that bar will never be nil right after calling it. Just like this:

```
func foo(param: inout Int?) {
    //Make sure that param can never be nil, but some default if it is nil
    param = param ?? 0
}

var bar: Int?

foo(param: &bar)

print("\(bar)") //Optional(0)
```

Everbody would consider that super bad practice, though, so you should rather not do it like this if not absolutely needed (which I don't think it is)

Comment: How to write a function that return a particular value for example [type] (not iptional)  ? we can put inside the func the if let condition but the main point is: should i return an empty array inside that function to avoid an exception in case the if let condition fails? the reason i am asking this is because with a returnrin function i am forced to return something. In your eye, is this a bad practice to create such type of func to avoid write everytime i call this function the if let/guard statements?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Optional.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map):

```
let i: Int? = 3

_ = i.map { unwrapped in
    //use the unwrapped value
    print(unwrapped)
}
```

Bear in mind that it returns a value, hence the `_ =`.